# How to make Date object toString via stringify use the regular toString instead of toStringISO in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, when I convert a Date object to string via JSON.stringify, it uses toStringISO by default. How can I change the prototype of it so that it uses the basic toString?

I have

```
var f = new Date("Mon May 27 2019 20:11:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)");
```

then if I do JSON.stringify(f) it gives me `"2019-05-28T00:11:13.000Z"`

but I want it to give me `"Mon May 27 2019 20:11:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"` (which I can get from f.toString()), how do I get that?

Looking to override prototype, something like that.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just use JSON.stringify(f.toString()) ?

Comment: `Date` has a `toJSON` method, which `JSON.stringify` calls to serialize the object to JSON.  You could probably replace `toJSON` with your own method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stringify dates with timezones properly in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332046/how-to-stringify-dates-with-timezones-properly-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) says this:

> - If the value has a `toJSON()` method, it's responsible to define what data will be serialized.
>
> ...
>
> - The instances of `Date` implement the `toJSON()` function by returning a string (the same as `date.toISOString()`). Thus, they are treated as strings.

If you wanted to change how every date is serialized, you can override `Date.toJSON`:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString() }
```

By replacing that method, now every date will be serialized using `Date.toString`:

```
var f = new Date(2019, 2, 3);
JSON.stringify(f)
```

This will work regardless of how deeply the date is nested inside your JSON structure, will work for every date, and will not require any customization to how you perform serialization.  The `JSON.stringify(f)` call shown above is probably what you would have used already.

If you wanted to change how a *particular* date is serialized, just replace that `Date` object's `toJSON` method:

```
var f = new Date(2019, 2, 3);
g = new Date();
f.toJSON = function() { return this.toString() };
JSON.stringify([f,g])
```

Which gives you this JSON:

```
"["Sun Mar 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)","2019-05-27T20:56:51.335Z"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `JSON.stringify` with a function:

```
JSON.stringify(objectToStringify, function (key, value) {
  if (value instanceof Date) {
    return (new Date(value)).toString(); // Or whatever you want to serialize it to
  }
  return value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` takes a function to replace values. Unfortunately, `Date.prototype.toJSON` gets called before it. If you want to avoid changing the prototype directly and can’t wrap/alter the date objects themselves, you can bypass this via the parent:

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
    return typeof value === 'string' && this[key] instanceof Date ?
        String(this[key]) :
        value;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: new Date("Mon May 27 2019 20:11:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"),
}, replacer));
```

Not the cleanest thing, but kind of contains the scope of altered behaviour.

Comment: "Unfortunately, Date.prototype.toJSON gets called before it." You can just `return (new Date(value)).toString();`

Comment: @ritaj: If you have mixed value types, you can’t know whether the string was originally a date.